ASP.NET error with ToListAsync for Entity Framework tables
I am working on a project to create rooms and user registers. In one part of the code, I get an error about one fold of the table entity (room) is null for some reason.
This is the code snippet (handler) that obtains a list of system rooms:
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    var adm = await _context.User.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == User.Identity.Name);

    if (adm != null)
    {
        Owner = adm;
    }

    var rooms = await _context.Room.ToListAsync();

    if (rooms.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach(var r in rooms)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Só o r: {r}");
            Console.WriteLine($"r + adm: {r.Adm}");
            Rooms.Add(r);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ViewData["RoomsEmpty"] = true;
    }
}

In the rooms data there are some fields, among them "adm" that contains the entity admin of the room which is the user´s own entity. When the code arrives on "foreach", this field (adm) stays null.
Thank you for helping me!

Welcome to the SO. "i have an error" - please add the error text.  Also please share your entities and the context setup. Also see [ask] and try always to provide a [mre].

Is Adm a related entity? If yes, don't you need to Include or Load it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data ?

Assume that the Adm is the related entity in Room class. By default, related entities are not automatically loaded unless explicitly included in the query. You need use the .Include() method:
var rooms = await _context.Room
    .Include(r => r.Adm) // navigation property
    .ToListAsync();

Reference:  Eager Loading of Related Data
